# Does libgdx support for webp format (image.webp) ? i want to decrease size of app

Tags: libgdx

I want to reduce APK size with WebP format.
I researched on internet and i see a commit of someone.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/3980
it says to have a submodule support for webp format. but how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/3980  is a closed (declined) merge request. Reason for the decline seems to be: "This is to big of a dependency and doesn't work on all platforms. I suggest you put this in a separate project and provide it as an extension."